# A question on joint probability distribution function

Tags: probability, integration, statistics

$f(x,y) = 2$, for $x>0, y>0, x+y<1$.

What is $P(X+Y>\frac{2}{3})$? I've looked at a lot of questions of this kind, but I couldn't understand the concept. If we were to solve this graphically, do we look for the area b/w the two lines $y=\frac{2}{3}-x$ and $y=1-x$? And if we solve this by integration, what will be the limits of integration?

Would really appreciate if someone could help me out, and make me understand the concept behind choosing the limits. Thanks.

Comment: It would be very useful to draw a picture. You just need to draw the lines $x+y = 1$ and $x+y= \frac{2}{3}$. Then calculate the area between these two lines (and, of course, limited by the axis lines). Hint: think triangles.

Comment: And if we were to solve it by integration? Btw yes, I see what you mean.

Comment: With integrals it's much more complicated ... But of course if you want, you can formulate the function of $y=y(x)$ so that you integrate over $x$ ... But it would have two different parts, as you would see from the picture.

Comment: If you don't know what the limits of integration will be, even then the picture will help you out. That is, if you are familiar with double integrals. (This is more a question about multiple integrals than statistics, so you might 
edit the tags).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you draw a picture, the domain of $f$ (where $f$ is $>0$) is just the bounded triangle $T$ bounded by the lines $x=0$, $y=0$ and $x+y =1$, of area $\frac{1}{2}$, so that indeed the total probability equals $1$ when integrated over that area.

In general $P((x,y) \in B)$, where $B$ is a measurable subset of the domain, is just $\int_B f(x,y)dxdy$ where we integrate over the area $B$. As $f$ is constantly $2$ here, it's also just $2\mu(B)$, where $\mu(B)$ is the Lebesgue measure ("area")  of $B$.

So to determine this graphically, compute the area of the part of the above-mentioned triangle $T$ that lies above the line $x+y=\frac{2}{3}$. The area below it inside $T$, is just a triangle of height and base $\frac{2}{3}$ and that has area $\frac{4}{18} = \frac{2}{9}$. So the asked for area is $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2}{9} = \frac{5}{18}$, and times $2$ for the factor of $f$ we get that $P(X+Y > \frac{2}{3})= \frac{5}{9}$.

If you want to use the double integral way, you can write the area as the union of $\{(x,y): 0 \le x \le \frac23 , \frac{2}{3} -x \le y \le 1-x\}$ (from the lower to the upper line) and $\{(x,y): \frac{2}{3} \le x \le 1: 0 \le y \le 1-x\}$ for the part between the $x$-axis and the line $x+y=1$.

So the analytical way (which I won't compute but trust will check out) gives

$$\int_0^{\frac23} \left( \int_{\frac23-x}^{1-x} 2 dy\right) dx + \int_{\frac23}^1 \left( \int_0^{1-x} 2dy \right) dx$$

as a repeated integral.

Comment: Thanks man, but what if I don't want to write the double integral in two different parts?

Comment: You have to use two parts because in the first area the upper and lower bounds are both linear in $x$ and in the second part the inner lower limit is constant. To compute the actual integrals we need "substitutable" values.... From the $y$ direction the situation is similar and we also need the sum of two integrals. The geometrical way is the easiest one, but only works here because of the simplicity of $f$.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, btw I was using the double integral with the limits of x being 0 and 1, and the limits of y being (2/3)-x and 1-x. The answer is clearly wrong, but what does that area represent?

Comment: @SonnyJordan then you also go through under the $x$-axis, but $f$ is $0$ there, it lies outside the support of $f$, so you get two much if you integrate $2$. on that whole strip.

Comment: Oh my god, thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to write down the integral:
$$
P(X+Y - \tfrac{2}{3} > 0) = \int\limits_{0}^{1} \int\limits_{0}^{1 - x}f(x,y)\theta(x+y - \tfrac{2}{3}) dydx
$$
Where $\theta(x) = 1$ if $x > 0$ and $\theta(x) = 0$ elsewhere. Now you have to adjust the boundaries to the range, where the $\theta$-function has finite contribution:
$$
y+x >  \tfrac{2}{3} \Rightarrow y > \tfrac{2}{3} -x
$$
So the final integral you need to solve is
$$
P(X+Y - \tfrac{2}{3} > 0) = \int\limits_{0}^{1} \int\limits_{\max(\tfrac{2}{3} -x,0)}^{1 - x}f(x,y) dydx = 2\int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{\max(\tfrac{2}{3} -x,0)}^{1 - x} dydx 
$$
Here max(a,b) ist the greater number between a and b.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.